# Using sdemon command of ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I am pretty new to ArcGIS for Server and ArcSDE but cannot find a solution in the Esri Documentation or Forums.

I don not know how to use **sdemon** or even where to start this command line tool.

Comment: Please chck out http://gisprog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/basicarcsd/

Comment: Thanks....but are the commands run in the Windows command line? or is there an ESRI Command line tool for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robert, if you are on 10.1, you need to install the [ArcSDE Command Line Tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcsde-application-server-microsoft-sql-server/10.1/index.html#//009500000047000000) separately by running the application server install program. The installation would be DBMS specific. Here is the reference for the [sdemon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcsde-application-server-microsoft-sql-server/10.1/index.html#/The_sdemon_command/00950000004n000000/) command in SQL Server, for instance. Otherwise, the full CMD commands reference is installed with this installation on your local machine, so you can always access it from the Start menu (assuming you are on Windows). The 10.0 version (no big difference with 10.1) is available [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/admin_cmds/support_files/admincmdref.htm).

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the Info. I am running AGS 10.0 with ARCSDE 9.3.1. Does this Apply?

Comment: Then you can access the .pdf file with the reference information for each command including the sdemon: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/geodatabase/pdf/admincmd.pdf and for installtion: http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geodatabases/9.3/installing-ArcSDE. The command reference and the necessary files for running the commands will be installed unitely.